# Unable to fix this issue: The following sections have been defined but not rendered for the section

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I know this question has been asked frequently on stackoverflow.  However, the solutions I have implemented have not fixed this error.

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".

In my _Layout.cshtml page, I have the following code:

```
    <footer>
      <p>&copy;</p>
    </footer>


@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

All the views I have created are find, however, the Register.cshtml and Login.cshtml, precreated by the asp.net mvc project end with the lines:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have tried taking these lines out, and trying many combinations, nonetheless, the issue has not been fixed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `required: false` means its optional so the error does not seem to relate to the code you have shown. Do you have any other `@RenderSection("scripts")` in the layout? Try also wrapping it in `@if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts")) { @RenderSection("scripts" }` and put a breakpoint on `@RenderSection()` and see if its hit.

Comment: Thank you, there is not other @RenderSection in the layout.  I followed your directions and the @RenderSection() was not hit.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine for me suggesting the issue is in code you have not shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have different case for the first letter in the layout and in page. Section names are case sensitive, so decide on something, say:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing!  Unfortunately, amending this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Just test changing case in my app and makes no difference (works fine for "SCriPtS")  suggesting section names are not case sensitive

Comment: As said by @user3559349, Section names are not case sensitive, please update your answer

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada, unfortunately there isn't much I can do about this answer, as OP marked it as accepted. "You cannot delete this accepted answer" when I try to delete it. THere isn't any other obvious reason for the error described in the post. If you have any idea what the answer is, feel free to post a new one, hopefully OP will notice and re-mark